# AWS インスタンスを、イメージを作成している途中で start しても問題ないか

Tags: aws

ec2 インスタンスをストップして、stopped の状態になったのちに、 CreateImage を行って、その後にインスタンスを再度 start する場合を考えます。

このとき、インスタンスの start は、 AMI の作成の完了を待つ必要がありますか？

というのも、 AMI の作成は、その操作が実行されると、「作成中」状態の AMI が作成されて、ある一定時間の後に、その AMI が ready になります。もし ready になる前に launch しても問題ないのだとしたら、 AMI 作成命令を行った時点でその時点のディスク情報はどこかしらに保持されていることになり、だったら何で AMI は一瞬で ready にならないのか、と疑問になります。怖いのは、AMI の作成は、元のインスタンスの、その時点のボリュームを利用しているパターンで、これが発生していた場合には、作成された AMI は不整合な状態になっている可能性があります。

この、 ec2 のインスタンスと AMI の動作の細かい仕様を見つけられずにいるので、質問しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@take88 に掲載してもらったリンク先を読み込んでみた結果、

- AMI 作成が pending になっている状態でも、その対象のインスタンスは start しても構わない。

のではないかと思うに至りました。

#### 理由

- AMI 作成ページの説明によれば、
  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html
  AMI は基本的にインスタンスを構成するボリュームに対する snapshot でもって構成されている。
- snapshot 作成のページによれば、
  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html
  "While it is completing, an in-progress snapshot is not affected by ongoing reads and writes to the volume."
  とあるので、 snapshot の作成は、元 volume の書き込みに対して影響を受けない。

Answer (score 0):

AMI作成時はボリュームのスナップショットが作成されますが、スナップショットは差分で取られるため、作成に数分単位で時間がかかると ドキュメントに書かれています。
ご参考) [Linux インスタンス用ユーザーガイド](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html)

そのため AMI が ready になるまで (少なくとも スナップショットの作成が終わるまでは) インスタンス側は 一貫した状態を保つ意味で 停止している必要があると思います。